# STAX Parser fails with large XML

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have encountered a very weird situation.
I have 2 XML's with me which I am trying to merge and form a single XML.
I am using STAX Parser to acheive it.

It works perfectly with Small files but fails when the file size is more than 300 KB which I believe is not very huge.

Not posting the XML or code here as it is very big.

Please find the error below

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32769
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl$ElementStack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.closeStartTag(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(Unknown Source)
```

There is no issue with the XML. Line at which I am getting the error is

**eventWriter.add(event);**. Here eventWriter is an instance of ***XMLEventWriter*** and event is of ***XMLEvent***

Let me know if anyone has faced the similar error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to resolve the above issue. It was nothing to do with STAX. There were some loop holes in the code which I have fixed now.